# How to generate column dependent random variable with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to generate a column of normal random variables with mean defined in the dep variable. However, I got the non-random results.

I know there are other ways to do it like apply functions (`sapply(1:5, rnorm, n=1)`), but I am just curious to know how to do it using dplyr and why I got the mistakes.

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame(dep = 1:5) %>% 
        mutate(normal_mean = rnorm(1, mean=dep))
Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

dep normal_mean
1   1    1.574045
2   2    1.574045
3   3    1.574045
4   4    1.574045
5   5    1.574045
```

Comment: actually I just found group by row using rowwise() resolve the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `rowwise` is very slow. Instead, you should just correct the first argument to `rnorm`:

```
data.frame(dep=1:5) %>% mutate(normal_mean = rnorm(n(), mean=dep))
```

Comment: The `nrow(.)` isn't working for me, but it can be replaced with `n()` if needed.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks, you're right (though both work for me). I'll switch to that, since it's more idiomatic. I'd been getting a lot of errors saying something like "No, don't use `n()` directly" lately, so I'd given up on it.

Comment: This also works when using other similar functions such as `base::sample` inside `dplyr::mutate`. E.g. `base::sample(x, n(), replace = TRUE)` instead of `base::sample(x, 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `rowwise()`

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame(dep = 1:5) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    normal_mean = rnorm(1, mean=dep)
  )

  dep normal_mean
1   1   2.0999493
2   2   0.8764449
3   3   6.4460789
4   4   3.2802778
5   5   4.6731459
```